public path not found in server.php
I am a new user and want to try a download admin panel to my computer, local host. The problem is public path is not found. How to fix that? Thanks
I want to know where is the public path in what folder and how to give the custom path to the home page.
the console is
WARN  PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'D:\company\multibranch-restaurant\multibranch-restaurant\public/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\company\multibranch-restaurant\multibranch-restaurant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\resources\server.php:16.
WARN  Stack trace:
WARN  #0 {main}.
WARN  thrown in D:\company\multibranch-restaurant\multibranch-restaurant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\resources\server.php on line 16.
2024-05-02 19:31:59 ............................................................. ~ 0s
